# Show that, Union of the point (0, 0) with closed line segments between $(0, 0)$ & $(1, 1/n)$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ is connected

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, connectedness

**Question**: Show that, Union of the point (0, 0) with closed line segments between $(0, 0)$ & $(1, \frac{1}{n})$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ is connected.

**My attempt**: I want to show this with general definition of connected set. So let given set be $S$. Suppose the contrary that $S$ is not connected. So that we have $S=A\cup B$ where $A$, $B$ are disjoint non empty open sets. Hence we have, either $ (0, 0)\in A$ or $(0, 0)\in B$. Without loss of generality, let $(0, 0)\in A$ then as, $A$ is an open set, so there exists neighborhood of $(0, 0)$ say, $N_{r_1}((0, 0))$ which is contained in $A$. Now, as $B$ is also an open set hence, there must be some point $(x, y)=(1,\frac{1}{m})\in B$ for some $m\in\mathbb{N}$ such that it's neighborhood say $N_{r_2}((1,\frac{1}{m}))$ is contained in $B$.

**How to proceed further?** please help.

(I think we have to some how show that these two neighborhoods are not disjoint! Which shows that $A$ and $B$ are not disjoint and then we get contradiction!)

Comment: You can't guarantee that $B$ will contain one of the endpoints of your segment. What you can say is that $B$ will have some point $(x,y)$ on some line segment, and then $A$ and $B$ are disconnecting this line segment and so...

Comment: @Jose27 Sir, how? I am unable to go further. Please help

Comment: @GeneralMathematics It should be easy from there. Segments are connected, and we are saying that $A$ and $B$ disconnect at least one such segment... do you think this is possible?

Comment: @K.Jiang sir, not getting your point. How proof follows? Though I know that, segments are path connected and hence connected. Please aren't there is any way to go with standard definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have more generally the following fact:

> If each element of $\{ A_i \}_{i \in I}$ contains a common point $x_0$, where $A_i$ is a connected subspace of $X$ for each $i \in I$, then $\bigcup_{i \in I} A_i$ is a connected subspace of $X$.

To show this, let $B = \bigcup_{i \in I} A_i$ and suppose for the sake of contradiction that $B$ is not connected. Then there exist non-empty, disjoint relatively open sets $C, D$ such that $B = C \cup D$. WLOG, suppose that $x_0 \in C$ (by disjointness of $C, D$, this means $x_0 \notin D$). Since each $A_i$ is connected and contains $x_0$, then it follows that $A_i \subseteq C$ for each $i \in I$. This implies $D = \emptyset$, contradicting the hypothesis.

To apply this to your problem is straightforward: obviously we let $X = \mathbb{R}^2$ in the usual topology, $x_0 = 0 \times 0$, $I = \mathbb{N}$, and $A_i$ be the closed line segment joining $0 \times 0$ and $1 \times \frac{1}{i}$. It's not hard to show that each $A_i$ is connected; we can, for instance, show that each $A_i$ is homeomorphic to $[0, 1] \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, which is connected. Therefore, the claim follows.

(Note: the fact that $A_i \sim [0, 1]$ for each $i \in I$ also shows that each $A_i$ is *path-connected*. The lemma proved above remains true by replacing "connected" with "path-connected". The original claim follows immediately since path-connectedness implies connectedness.)

---

**EDIT: Another example**

If we now consider the space $E = B \cup \{1 \times 0\}$, where $B$ is as defined before, we show that $E$ is connected. We can't apply the previous lemma because $\{1 \times 0\}$ does not contain the "common" point $0 \times 0$. However, we have the following fact:

> If a subspace $A \subseteq X$ is connected, and $B$ is such that $A \subseteq B \subseteq {\rm Cl} A$, where ${\rm Cl} A$ is the *closure* of $A$ in $X$, then $B$ is connected.

To prove it, suppose $B$ admits a separation $B = C' \cup D'$, where $C', D'$ are non-empty disjoint sets open in $B$ under the subspace topology. Then there exist $C, D$ open in $X$ such that $C' = B \cap C$ and $D' = B \cap D$. Consider the sets $C'' = A \cap C$ and $D'' = A \cap D$. By definition, they are open in $A$ under the subspace topology. Since $C', D'$ are disjoint and $A \subseteq B$, it follows that $C'', D''$ must be disjoint. Now, we show that $C'', D''$ are not empty. Suppose for the sake of contradiction that $C'' = \emptyset$. This implies $C$ does not intersect $A$. Now consider an arbitrary $c_0 \in C' = B \cap C$; note that $c_0 \in C$ and $c_0 \in {\rm Cl} A$. The second fact means that every neighborhood of $c_0$ intersects $A$. The first fact means that $C$ is a neighborhood of $c_0$. Taken together, $C$ must intersect $A$, a contradiction, so $C''$ must be non-empty. A similar argument applies to show $D''$ is non-empty. Then $C'', D''$ constitute a separation of $A$, contradicting the hypothesis that $A$ is connected.

Now applying this fact to your problem, you can show that

$${\rm Cl} B = B \cup ([0, 1] \times 0)$$

where $[0, 1] \times 0$ is simply the closed line segment joining $0 \times 0$ and $1 \times 0$. Note that

$$B \subseteq E = B \cup \{1 \times 0\} \subseteq {\rm Cl} B$$

Therefore, by the fact proved above, $E$ must be connected.

(Your intuition that $E$ is not *path*-connected is correct, as there exists no path between $1 \times 0$ and any other point of $E$.)

Comment: Sir, how the set $D$ become empty set, in the proof?

Comment: If $A_i \subseteq C$ for each $i \in I$, then we have that $B = \bigcup_{i \in I} A_i \subseteq C$. But $C \subseteq B$, so it follows that $C = B$. Then, since $C, D$ are disjoint and $C \cup D = B$, we must have $D = \emptyset$.

Comment: Thank you so much sir. Got it. I can't upvote your answer because for upvoting an answer we need atleast+15 reputations. Further, I am interested to see if there are any other methods to solve this question without using above result/fact.

Comment: Great, glad to help!

Comment: sir, actually I had done little typo while posting a question. But, it's ok because I found your answer very useful. Sir the question that I want to post is, "is the union of $(1, 0)$ with closed line segment between $(0, 0)$ and $(1, 1/n) $ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ is connected? " ( Is the same theorem/result apple here, Further, what about path connectedness)

Comment: No, you cannot apply the lemma in this case, since the space $\{ 1 \times 0 \}$ does not contain $x_0 = 0 \times 0$. That set is indeed connected (not path-connected though), but to show that, we need something more. Will update my answer for that case.

Comment: Thank you so much sir your for reply. I will wait for update.

Comment: Sir, can you elaborate more about path connectedness? Since point $(1, 0)$ is in the set $E$ and as every close line segment joining $(0, 0)$ and $(1, 1/n)$ is in $E$, so we can see that, as $n$ tends to $∞$ we get the line segment joining $(0, 0)$ and $(1, 0)$ so isn't there is path? Or am I wrong...

Comment: Sir, In particular how can we show that "there no path joining $(1, 0)$ to other points of $E$?

Comment: A space $X$ is path-connected if for every pair of points $x_0, x_1 \in X$, there is a path from $x_0$ to $x_1$. A path from $x_0$ to $x_1$ is a continuous function $f: [0, 1] \to X$ such that $f (0) = x_0$ and $f (1) = x_1$.

Comment: Yes, it is true that $\lim_{n \to \infty} A_n = [0, 1] \times 0$; however, this does not imply that $A_n = [0, 1] \times 0$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$. And this in fact is key. For any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, the neighborhood $B_d \left( 1 \times 0, \frac{1}{2 n} \right)$ is disjoint from the closed line segment joining $0 \times 0$ and $1 \times \frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: Sir, Got it. Big thank you for your help.

Comment: May be I am wrong! But there is little correction in a proof: as $C, D$ are open sets in $B$. So they belongs to topology for $B$ and hence they are the intersection of $B$ with some open sets in $X$. Hence There exists open sets $C'$ and $D'$ in $X$ such that, $C=B\cap C'$ and $D=B\cap D'$.

Comment: Hence accordingly proof changes.. Like, we have to consider, $C"=A\cap C'$ and $D"=A\cap D'$ which are open in $A$(since $C'$ and $D'$ are open in $X$) am I wrong sir?

Comment: Yes @GeneralMathematics, I made a typo. Fixing it!

Comment: But, how to show that $C"$ and $D"$ are disjoint? , let $x\in C"\cap D"$ then $x\in C"$ and $x\in D"$ this imply, $x\in A\cap C$ and $x\in A\cap D$ ....?

Comment: $A \subseteq B$ means that $C'' = A \cap C \subseteq C' = B \cap C$ and $D'' = A \cap D \subseteq D' = B \cap D$. Now, if $C', D'$ are disjoint, can you see how this means the smaller sets $C'', D''$ must also be disjoint?

Comment: $\text{Now it's clear}$

Comment: Sir, how $C"$ and $D"$ constitutes separation of $A$? Since, for this, we must have, $A=C"\cup D"$ But, here $C"\cup D"=(A\cap C)\cup (A\cap D) $ which not $A$?

Comment: Sir, Am I correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148577/discussion-between-k-jiang-and-general-mathematics).