# Is $A$ is disconnected if some subset of $A$ has separation?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I have asked a question here, [Show that, Union of the point (0, 0) with closed line segments between $(0, 0)$ & $(1, 1/n)$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ is connected](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4768218/1206247)

In the second part of answer,that is, in proof of the result

> If a subspace $A \subseteq X$ is connected, and $B$ is such that $A \subseteq B \subseteq {\rm Cl} A$, where ${\rm Cl} A$ is the *closure* of $A$ in $X$, then $B$ is connected.

it is shown that, $C"$, $D"$ are nonempty disjoint open subsets of $A$ and they form sepration of $A$. **But How** they form sepration of $A$? (**I think** there union is **not** $A$. Since $C"\cup D"=(A\cap C)\cup (A\cap D)≠A$? Hence they can't form sepration of $A$.So we can't show $A$ is not connected. Hence we can't get contradiction)
**So is the proof wrong?**

Further,from above there arises another **question**

> 

Let $A$ subset of topological space $X$, If we have found two nonempty disjoint open subsets of $A$ whose union may not be $A$ then $A$ is disconnected?

Comment: What makes you think $(A\cap C)\cup (A\cap D)\neq A$? Clearly from the linked proof $C\cup D\supseteq B\supseteq A$, so $(A\cap C)\cup (A\cap D)=A\cap (C\cup D)=A$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof is correct. In the answer $A \subseteq B \subseteq \overline A$, and $$B = C' \cup D'=(B\cap C)\cup (B \cap D)=B\cap(C\cup D)$$
which means that $B\subseteq C\cup D$, and since $A\subseteq B$,$$(A∩C)∪(A∩D)=A\cap(C\cup D)=A$$

Your last question is absurd. $(0,1)$ and $(2,3)$ are disjoint open subsets of $\mathbb R$. Is $\mathbb R$ disconnected?